# How to add custom label to clicked Marker using react-google-maps libary?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, marker

i recently watched a tutorial how to use react-google-maps libary but at the end I failed to find out how to achieve the following:

My app read coordinate from file and present it on map as markers. Can someone tell me now how when I click on specific marker can set a label "1", and for next one "2" etc. ? Here is my code

```
function Map() {
    const [selectedPark, setSelectedPark] = useState(null)
  return (
      <GoogleMap defaultZoom={10} defaultCenter={{lat: 45.421532, lng: -75.697189}}>
          {parksData.features.map( park =>(
              <Marker position={{lat: park.geometry.coordinates[1] , lng:  park.geometry.coordinates[0]}} 
 label="0" onClick={()=>
                  setSelectedPark(park)}/>
          ))}
          {selectedPark && (
              <InfoWindow position={{ lat: selectedPark.geometry.coordinates[1], lng: selectedPark.geometry.coordinates[0]}}
              onCloseClick={()=> {
                  setSelectedPark(null)
              }}>
    <div>test</div>
              </InfoWindow>
          )}
      </GoogleMap>
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, [react-google-maps Marker](https://tomchentw.github.io/react-google-maps/#marker) does not support the [`setLabel` method](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers#marker_labels) of Google Maps Marker object. For your use case you need to manipulate the value of your `Marker's label` attribute using conditions and states.

You can check this [code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/markerlabelchange-knowwg?file=index.js) on how I change the label when I click a marker.
First of, I have this state. `markerid` to mark the current marker, `label` set a number type to manipulate the number numerically and 0 as starting number.

```
    this.state = {
      markerid: '',
      label: 0
    };
```

Here's my function every time a Marker is clicked where I first get the value of the state label then add 1 so that it will increase to one everytime marker is clicked.then I set the state of the label to the new number and set the markerid state to the id of the marker that was clicked.

```
onMarkerClick = id => {
    var labelCount = this.state.label + 1;
    this.setState({
      markerid: id,
      label: labelCount
    });
  };
```

Here's my Marker component where I map my json data to a marker. Since we are using a Marker component in a loop, if we directly put a state value for the label, it will change to all the marker. To do that, I use a condition that will check if the clicked marker(markerid state) is equal to a specific marker.id of the loop and it will set the label of only that marker. I also change the marker state to string since the label requires a string type and not a number. The only thing about this code is that it does not retain the label after you click another marker.

```
 {data.map((marker, key) => (
          <Marker
            key={key}
            position={{ lat: marker.lat, lng: marker.lng }}
            onClick={() => this.onMarkerClick(marker.id)}
            {...this.state.markerid === marker.id && {
              label: this.state.label.toString()
            }}
          />
        ))}
```